# SharePoint windows Authentication with Custom Authorization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, authorization

Is there any way to configure windows Authentication with Custom Authorization in SharePoint 2013/2016. We want user to be authenticated with window credentials and SharePoint objects should be accessible based on access mapping rule configured in another external data source (Oracle/SQL). SharePoint search should also display the result based on external access mapping.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to technically do this but none of them are good ideas, so I'm just going to say, no, you cannot do this.

Honestly I can't think of any reason why you'd want to introduce massive potential failure points to replicate such a critical feature that you get free out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Derek Gusoff is correct while it is possible, I would never recommend setting something like this up.

Please let me know what the requirements are for your solution and what you are trying to accomplish.  There maybe an easier solution.